# Blogger no longer respects the chosen dynamic view

Tags: html, css, url-routing, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have a [Blogger site](http://www.alesserfate.com) with CSS customized dynamic view template, where each section on the menu had a default view (magazine, flipcard, mosaic).

I say "had", because recently I've noticed that Blogger does not longer respect the choosen view, when passing from one section to another which has a different view (for example url: from ?view=mosaic to ?view=flipcard). I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem, or if there is a way to "force" a certain view, as formerly.

I'm no expert at all, but i think the fastest solution should be finding a way to 'force' the browser on refreshing the URL query strings. For example, when I navigate from

www.alesserfate.com/search/label/audioKB?view=timeslide

to

www.alesserfate.com/search/label/videogame?view=mosaic,

, and then back to the first link, the URL query "?view=timeslide" seems to be overridden and the page is displayed with the (wrong) mosaic view.There must be a way to fix this ("forcing" to refresh url query?). I want to emphasize that, this behaviour is NEW ,without touching anything on the blog. Definitely Google has changed something under Blogger's hood.